# How do I copy an object that is inside a hierarchy without transforming it?

Tags: interface

How do I copy an object that is inside a hierarchy (while keeping the copy inside the same hierarchy as the original) and without transforming it?

If I select the object and hit Shift+D it is transformed, unless I hit the right mousebutton, which seems to cancel to transform, but is that the only way? Is it possible to turn off the 'transform thing'?

I’ve been using Maya and Softimage for many years, so I’m not new to 3d-software, but this doesn’t make much sense to me :-)

Comment: Typically, I'll shift D, esc.  I don't think there's a way to make it so you don't have to hit esc to cancel the grab part of the duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That seems like an unnecessary extra step that should at least be possible to turn off in the settings. Where can I contact the developers about this?